# Installation of Thredds Data Server

Tags: thredds

I am trying to deploy `Thredds` war file in the `Apache Tomcat 7` server on `Windows Server 2012 R2`.

When I started threads data server it is showing error massage like:

> Application at context path/Thredds could not found.

I also gone through the `Thredds` server log files there error massage is displaying looks like:

> tds.content.root.path property isn't defined.

How can I set `tds.content.root.path` property in the `tds.properties` file or using `Java` system properties ?

Please Guys help me out for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to specify `tds.content.root.path` in your `<tomcat_home>/bin/setenv.bat`. There's a tutorial for server setup [here](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/tds/tutorial/GettingStarted.html). It's Unix-centric, but hopefully you can use it to do the analogous configuration on Windows.

Comment: Thanks  Christain for giving response.

Comment: Thanks Christain for giving response. Ya I have already gone through the tutorial for setting up TDS as provided by Unidata site but it is only for linux. I tried same steps in windows also but I get stuck in the setting up the tds.content.root.path properties.

Comment: Can any one explain here step by step process of installation Thredds Data server on  windows server 2012 R2.